# Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :

Tags: r

I am trying to follow this set of R tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_pvHnqkVCE

It features the line:

```
devtools::install_github("psyteachr/msc-data-skills")
```

However, when I try to run that line of code I receive:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘processx’
```

Does anyone know how I can solve that?

Comment: What happens when you run `install.packages("processx")`?

Comment: @MrFlick this fixed the issue, thanks! Do you want to make it the answer so I can award it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reinstall Rtools:
See: https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-devtools-need-to-update-processx-version/34639/4

Comment: Thanks for trying. Reinstalling did not work, unfortunately. Do you know if I need to do anything using Rtools once it is installed? Eg do I have to run it or import it separately into Rstudio?